# How to sort posts list based on different sorting criteria in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am building social network app. i have used node.js(express) and mongodb as backend.

Now, i want to list all posts based on different sorting critrea.
user can set his business category(optional). i have store each user current location in user documents.

Now, i need the post list of all user including friends based on below sorting criteria

- post from near by friends (lowest distance first)
- post from user who has same category as logged in user if logged in user has set business category
- post from user who has different business category
- post from user who has not set business category (latest first(created at desc))

how should i build structure for friend system in order to achieve above sorting posts?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you should pay attention to the memory - this structure grows with N^2 speed where N - posts count.

This task seems to be quiet complex so I suggest to add some logic on backend.

For example, look at CQRS+ES (I think it's suitable technology in your case). So, posts are events and you would have sorted list for every user on read side. And you would update all these structures on every post. (You can read about CQRS here http://cqrs.nu/ and check simple CQRS framework with express support here https://reimagined.github.io/resolve )

In addition I recomend you to limit posts count for every users' list.